# How to create subelements of a NumPy Array by taking in consideration a criteria in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am currently working on Python 3.8 with a NumPy object array and I try to extract some subelements from this NumPy Array respecting a criteria.

For example, if I take in consideration this NumPy Array :
[image]

I have some values set to 0 and some !=0.

I would like to be able to extract some specific subelements from this array just by taking into account the values set to 0.
An example of what I would like to extract is given in this picture :

[image]

The borders of the subelements are defined by the borders of the NumPy Array by itself, by the fact that there are some neighbors with values !=0 and some neighbors with "Nan" values ... at the end I am more interested by the "contour" of these subelements.

At the moment, I don't really know how to solve this problem, I am questioning myself on how to get the borders correctly, how to move in the NumPy Array in order to collect all the cells needed ...

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to approach this problem, one way I could think of is to directly use a comparision operator.

Example ( [Source: numpy docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) )

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [0.3, 0.41, 0.47], [0.21, 0.23, 0.97]])
a > 0
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

This gives you an idea of what elements are non zero

The other way is to use the built in method `np.nonzero`

```
>>> a
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0.3, 0.41, 0.47],
       [0.21, 0.23, None]], dtype=object)
>>> a[np.nonzero(a)]
array([0.3, 0.41, 0.47, 0.21, 0.23], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don't think this solve my problem, in fact there is a notion of "neighbors" in my case, getting the indexes of the elements that are equal to 0 is not enough, I need to get the indexes of the elements which are equal to 0 and their neighbors if they are also equal to 0 in order to create a subelement. This subelement has boundaries which are formed by cells which are not equal to 0.